# Performant alternative to Ruby none?

Tags: ruby

Does Ruby's none? method still loop through all the elements of an array even if the condition evaluates to true before the last element?  The docs do not specify, and on some further inspection, I can get some interesting results...

```
arr = [3, 4, 5, 6]

arr.none? {|e| p e > 4 }
false
false
true
=> false

arr.none? {|e| puts e > 4 }
false
false
true
true
=> true
```

Puts doesn't return the object though, so none? returns true in that example because print e > 4 neither evaluates to true nor false; therefore, the block never returns true for all the elements?

Since p does return the object, I am led to conclude that none? does in fact stop when the block first evaluates to true, but I'm not 100% sure.

If it does loop through all the elements no matter what, why?  What's the most performant alternative?  The method returns a boolean, so  it should just stop the first time it evaluates to true and return false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is just a fundamental misunderstanding between what is true and false in ruby.

In ruby every object is either "truthy" or "falsey". (and everything is an object)

- Falsey Objects: `NilClass` (`nil`) and `FalseClass` (`false`)
- Truthy Objects: Everything else

For Example:

```
[1,"a",Object,nil,false].map do |o| 
  [o,o ? true : false]
end 
#=> [[1, true],
#    ["a",true]
#    [Object,true]
#    [nil, false]
#    [false,false]
```

So now to answer your question:

Yes `none?` short circuits. (Stops at the first "truthy" value). As your first example shows.

Your second example uses `puts`. `puts` always returns `nil` and since `nil` is "falsey" and `none?` is looking for "truthy" values the loop continues until the end.